# How to store a static variable in desktop application designed in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I start my desktop app with a login, validate the user and "redirect" to the index Jframe.

What I want now is to store a user Object obtained from login so that it's available in all jframes that I'll use later.

Is it possible? I know that session variables are not that useful in desktop apps but I can't seem to find the way to create a static variable.

I tried creating my Object user in  main, then setting it up after login. But it couldn't find the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a static variable:

```
public class MyAppContext {
    public static volatile Object loginObject;
}

MyAppContext.loginObject = "whatever";
```

Or use a framework like Spring to manage your contexts.